# Value not found error when trying to use type aliasing for Set in scala

Tags: scala, types

Why does this not work in scala?

```
type IntSet = scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int]

IntSet(1)
```

I get "IntSet not found"

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `IntSet(1)` is equivalent to `IntSet.apply(1)`, where `IntSet` is an object, not a class/trait.

The problem is that you've defined an alias for the [`Set[A]` *trait*](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set), but not for its [companion object](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Set$).

If you want `apply` to work for your type alias `IntSet`, you'll have to define an object named `IntSet` as well.

```
object IntSet {
  def apply[A](elems: Int*): IntSet = Set(elems: _*)
}
```

Now this will compile:

```
IntSet(1)
```

Comment: Thanks dcastro. Just on the side, what does the underscore mean in this expression. Set(elems: _*) 

i am new to Scala.

Comment: @AbdulRahman I'm not exactly sure of the meaning of `_` here, but I know this is used to "make varargs work", when passing them from a method to another. Without it, `elems` would be inferred as a `Seq[Int]` and `Set(elems)` would produce a `Set[Seq[Int]]` with one element. The `: T` syntax in general, is called [*type ascription*](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/types.html).

Comment: @AbdulRahman `The last argument in an application may be marked as a sequence argument, e.g. e: _*. ...` http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#function-applications